# Creating a trifold Paper example in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create trifold pamphlet example using ThreeJS. I have got it almost correct except one small part. I am trying to fold the pages on to the **side0**. **side1** - green and **side2** - red get folded onto the **side0**. I am using `PlaneGeometry` to create page like effect.

[image]

Green part is folding properly on it's axis on right side but the red part is folding on it's axis on top. I have tried setting the **rotation.x** and **rotation.y** property but couldn't get the hold of red cube.

I have created a JS Fiddle for it:
https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/w35mjrwf/

Below is the code:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var sides = [];
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

init();
animate();


function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1).setLength(5);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


  var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  var side0 = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "red",
    wireframe: true
  }));
  scene.add(side0);
  sides.push(side0);

  var side1Geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  side1Geom.translate(-0.5, 0, 0);

  var side2Geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1);
  side2Geom.translate(-0.5, 0, 0);



  var side1 = new THREE.Mesh(side1Geom);
  sides.push(side1);

  var side2 = new THREE.Mesh(side2Geom);
  sides.push(side2);

  side1.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "green",
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  side2.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "red",
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  side1.position.set(-0.5, 0, 0);
  side0.add(side1);

  side2.position.set(1, 0.5, 0);
  side2.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;

  //side2.position.set(1.5,0,0);
  side0.add(side2);

  document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", foldTheCube);
}

function foldTheCube() {
  var start = {
    value: -Math.PI / 2
  };
  var finish = {
    value: Math.PI / 2
  };
  var angle = 0;

  var tween1 = new TWEEN
    .Tween(start)
    .to(finish, 3000)
    //.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
    .onUpdate(function() {
      angle = this.value;
      sides[1].rotation.y = angle + 1.6;
      sides[2].rotation.x = -angle - 1.6;
    })
    .start()
    .onComplete(function() {
      /*var tween2 = new TWEEN
       .Tween(start)
       .to(finish, 3000)
       .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
       .onUpdate(function(){
        angle = this.value;
         sides[1].rotation.x = -1.5;
           sides[2].rotation.y = -2.15;
       })
       tween2.start();*/
      var tween2 = new TWEEN
        .Tween(start)
        .to(finish, 3000)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
        .onUpdate(function() {
          angle = this.value;
          sides[0].rotation.x = 1.5;
          // sides[2].rotation.y = -2.15;
        }); //tween2.start();
    });
}



function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update();
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<!-- TheJim01: Adding dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="run" value="run" />
```

I need to rotate red section just like green one but towards left.

Comment: In your JSfiddle I'm seeing six planes that fold neatly into a cube, rotating from all edges. Does this mean you figured it out?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/w35mjrwf/